# Symfony Monolog - No HTTP Request data included - Where is call coming from?

Tags: php, symfony, monolog

I am working on my first Symfony WebApp project. I have setup Monolog to send critical errors by mail and to include HTTP Request data:

```
//config.yml
services:
    monolog.processor.web:
        class: Monolog\Processor\WebProcessor
        tags:
            - { name: monolog.processor, handler: error_group }
    monolog.formatter.extended:
        class: Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter
        arguments:
            format: "[%%datetime%%] %%channel%%.%%level_name%%:\n   MESSAGE: %%message%%\n   CONTEXT: %%context%%\n   IP: %%extra.ip%%\n   METHOD: %%extra.http_method%%\n   URL: %%extra.url%%\n   SERVER: %%extra.server%%\n   REF: %%extra.referrer%%\n\n"
            allowInlineLineBreaks: true
            ignoreEmptyContextAndExtra: true
        calls:
            - [includeStacktraces]


monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type:         fingers_crossed
            action_level: debug
            handler:      main_group
        main_group:
            type:    group            
            members: [default_log, error_group]        
        default_log:
            type:  stream
            path:  %kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log
            level: debug   
        error_group:
            type:    group            
            members: [error_log, mail_buffer]             
        error_log:
            type:  stream
            path:  %kernel.logs_dir%/errors_%kernel.environment%.log
            level: error
            formatter: monolog.formatter.extended
        mail_buffer:
            type:    buffer
            handler: mailer
        mailer:
            type:       swift_mailer
            from_email: "my_mail_address"
            to_email:   "my_mail_address"
            subject:    ERROR!
            level:      error 
            formatter:  monolog.formatter.extended
```

This works fine. All critical errors are logged in an additional file and send by mail with a good readable format, e.g.:

```
[1] request.ERROR:
  MESSAGE: Uncaught PHP Exception ..
  CONTEXT: {"exception":"[object] ..."}
  IP: 1.2.3.4
  METHOD: GET
  URL: /about
  SERVER: www.my-server.xx
  REF: http://www.my-server.xx/info
```

Every night (not always the same time) I receive a hand full error-mails showing an exception due to an invalid route. The strange thing: These log messages include no HTTP Request data:

```
  IP: %extra.ip%
  METHOD: %extra.http_method%
  URL: %extra.url%
  SERVER: %extra.server%
  REF: %extra.referrer%
```

How is this possible? The only explanation for the missing Request data is, that the call was made directly to PHP but not via HTTP at all. Is this correct or could there be other explanations? I have set up no cron job or any other services that would access the web app directly via PHP or something like this. So were is the call coming from?

I am working on shared hosting webspace, so I have no access to any other server log files. Any idea how I can track down the source of these calls?